# How to force dotnet nuget to use system certificate in dockerfile?

Tags: c#, docker, ssl, .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to build a docker image for my donet core 7 application.
I'm behind a corporate proxy, so I added the following lines to my dockerfile:

```
FROM   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build    
COPY ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
ENV http_proxy http://proxy-server:8080
ENV https_proxy http://proxy-server:8080
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://proxy-server:8080
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://proxy-server:8080
RUN dotnet restore "src/Api/PositionApi/PositionApi.csproj"
```

When running the docker build command , i'm getting an error on the `dotnet restore` command, during the nuget packages download:

> #23 1.995 info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the fallback certificate bundle at
> '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.402/trustedroots/codesignctl.pem'.
> #23 2.020 info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the fallback certificate bundle at
> '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.402/trustedroots/timestampctl.pem'.
> #23 2.024 info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' into project '/src/src.csproj'.
> #23 8.825 error: Unable to load the service index for source http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
> #23 8.825 error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> #23 8.825 error:   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Why the dotnet restore command is ignoring my certificate ? and how configure the dotnet cli to use the os certificate instead of relying on '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.402/trustedroots/timestampctl.pem' ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested `curl` or `wget` or anything else to ensure that you set up the CA certificate correctly?  I'm not an expert, so I have no idea what the solution is, but I've often seen people run a command similar to `update-ca-certificates` after copying the certificate so that OpenSSL knows about it.

Comment: curl and wget are working without any issue after calling update-ca-certificates

Comment: I assume this means that nuget still does not work.  Can you try `dotnet new console ; echo 'await (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");' > Program.cs ; dotnet run`. This doesn't need any packages, so restore will complete successfully. If HttpClient can't reach api.nuget.org, then the problem is "lower level" than NuGet.